# Cannot connect to PostgresSQL through Google-Cloud-Proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow, google-cloud-composer, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm running a test Python script that uploads a small amount of data to a PostgreSQL database using SQL Alchemy. Apache Airflow (hosted by Google Cloud Composer) is running this script on a schedule. The script always runs totally fine whenever I run it on Airflow locally and connect directly to the DB.

When I run it on Cloud Composer however, I need to connect through Google's Cloud SQL Proxy for security reasons.

Here's the weird part - the script runs fine about 50% of the time when connecting through Google's cloud-sql-proxy. The other 50% of the time I get the error `(psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "XXXX`. And then usually it retries and it connects just fine.

I'm assuming it's probably something to do with how I am managing my connection (how it's being opened, pooled, or closed) so here is how I'm doing that. I'm using SQLAlchemy in my Python script like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOST}/{DB_NAME}")
conn = engine.connect()
# Upload a bit of data here
conn.close()
engine.dispose()
```

I've always used this way of uploading data locally so I'm a bit confused why that wouldn't work with Google Cloud Proxy / Google Cloud Composer (hosted Airflow).

Comment: Since this is intermittent, let's gather more information. 1) Is the user in the error a system user or a custom user? 2) Please share the whole error since it is possible that other details can help.  3) For replication purposes could you confirm if you are following [this procedure](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#sqlalchemy-tcp)? I'm daring to suspect that issue can be caused on the proxy initialization, for example, a configuration to connect to multiple instances with the same user but different user (I'm just imagining all possible scenarios).